# listview update with spinner and AlertDialog

Tags: android, listview

I have a problem with updating the listview, pressing the "OK" button, modifying the registry in the database, but the value entered in the listview is not reflected.

Annex the activities and the class adapter.

Any help would be appreciated as I have searched and have not found it.

thanks
Carlos

```
    EditText edt3;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.pedidos);

        pbr2 = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar2);
        listap = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview2);
        spinnerFam = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);

        connectionClass = new ConnectionClass();
        helper = new DBHelper(this);
        db = helper.getWritableDatabase();

        gruposAdapter = new GruposAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,helper.recuperarGrupos());
        gruposAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

        spinnerFam.setAdapter(gruposAdapter);
        spinnerFam.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

        productosList = helper.recuperarProductos();
        productosAdapter = new ProductosAdapter(this,productosList);
        listap.setAdapter(productosAdapter);

        listap.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                Productos productos = productosAdapter.getItem(i);
                final String idprod = productos.getCodigo();

                LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
                final View dialoglayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog,null);
                final EditText etcant = (EditText) dialoglayout.findViewById(R.id.editText4);
                final TextView tvcant = (TextView) dialoglayout.findViewById(R.id.textView15);

                tvcant.setText(productos.getDescripcion());
                etcant.setText(String.valueOf(productos.getCantidad()));
                etcant.setSelectAllOnFocus(true);

                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Pedidos.this);
                builder.setView(dialoglayout);

                builder.setPositiveButton("Aceptar", new  DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        Integer cantidad = Integer.valueOf(etcant.getText().toString());
                        helper.actualizarCantProd(idprod,cantidad);

                    }
                });

                builder.setNegativeButton("Cancelar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

                    }
                });

                builder.show();
                productosAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
               // Toast.makeText(Pedidos.this, codspinini, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
       Grupos grupos = gruposAdapter.getItem(position);
        productosAdapter.getFilter().filter(Long.toString(grupos.getCodGrup()), new Filter.FilterListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFilterComplete(int i) {
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

    }

}

public class ProductosAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable {
    private LayoutInflater pLayoutInflater;
    private List<Productos> productosList;
    private List<Productos> productosFilterList;
    private ProductosFilter productosFilter;
    private Context context;

    public ProductosAdapter(Context context, List data){
        productosList = data;
        productosFilterList = data;
        pLayoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return productosList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Productos getItem(int i) {
        return productosList.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return i;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        View updateViewp;
        final ViewHoler viewHoler;
        if (view == null){
            updateViewp = pLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.productodetalle, null);
            viewHoler = new ViewHoler();

            viewHoler.cantidad = (TextView) updateViewp.findViewById(R.id.textView14);
            viewHoler.codigo = (TextView) updateViewp.findViewById(R.id.textView11);
            viewHoler.descripcion = (TextView) updateViewp.findViewById(R.id.textView12);
            viewHoler.precio = (TextView) updateViewp.findViewById(R.id.textView13);

            updateViewp.setTag(viewHoler);
        } else {
            updateViewp = view;
            viewHoler = (ViewHoler) updateViewp.getTag();
        }
        final Productos item = getItem(i);
            viewHoler.cantidad.setText(String.valueOf(item.getCantidad()));
            viewHoler.codigo.setText(item.getCodigo());
            viewHoler.precio.setText(String.valueOf(item.getPrecioNeto()));
            viewHoler.descripcion.setText(item.getDescripcion());

        return updateViewp;
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        if (productosFilter == null){
            productosFilter = new ProductosFilter();
        }
        return productosFilter;
    }

    static class ViewHoler {
        TextView cantidad;
        TextView descripcion;
        TextView codigo;
        TextView precio;
    }


    private class ProductosFilter extends Filter {

        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence charSequence) {
            long codGrupId = Long.parseLong(charSequence.toString());
            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();

            if (codGrupId > 0) {
                ArrayList<Productos> filterListp = new ArrayList<Productos>();
                for (int i = 0; i < productosFilterList.size(); i ++) {
                    if ((productosFilterList.get(i).getCodgrupo()) == codGrupId){
                        Productos productos = productosFilterList.get(i);
                        filterListp.add(productos);
                    }
                }
                results.count = filterListp.size();
                results.values = filterListp;
            } else {
                results.count = productosFilterList.size();
                results.values = productosFilterList;
            }

            return results;
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence charSequence, FilterResults filterResults) {
            productosList = (ArrayList<Productos>)filterResults.values;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

May be you should notifyDataSetChange in your dialog's positive button onclick listener like this:

```
builder.setPositiveButton("Aceptar", new  DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    Integer cantidad = Integer.valueOf(etcant.getText().toString());
                    helper.actualizarCantProd(idprod,cantidad);
                    productosAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            });
```

Comment: Thanks for replying, add the notifyDataSetChange but the listview is not updated.